Move Azure DevOps Work Items from One Organization to Another
I am looking ways to move Azure DevOps Work Items from One Organization to Another as there is no official method. The below are ideas but I need best option.
Solutions found

To do it by Installing the Azure DevOps Office Integration Tool, but it requires system admin permissions.

Manual by using import and export in excel.

Using API to list the work items, but unable to push this info into another organization project, not clear how to do using which API.
Eg: curl -u : "https://dev.azure.com/**/Project/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=111&api-
version=7.1-preview.3"



This question is similar to: How do I move Work Items from one organization to another. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A popular method is using the Azure DevOps Migration Tools. It can bulk migrate Work Items.
You can reference the following articles to set up the configuration file for Work Items Migration:

Getting Started
WorkItemMigrationContext


This migration tool doesn't appear to be official, hence will make it difficult to adopt in organization. What about using API's ?

@Salman, Using API might also work but is quite complex. You need to write the scripts by yourself to call series of the APIs to list all the work items and get details of each work item from the organization, and then create new work items to another organization. I do not think it is a good method.

can you pls help me correct this API call ----> curl "https://dev.azure.com/online/NewRelic/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=7.1-preview.3" -H "Authorization: Bearer cacc" -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" --data-binary '[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"Test bug by salman"}]'

Output: Object moved
Object moved to here.

@Salman, What do you want to do using the API?

Trying to Create a bug with only required fields. Basically i am able to list the work items using API, now i am working towards API call to inject to another organization work item separately for now, later will try to merge both in single script. Just looking for alternate ways.

@Salman, I noticed that @Kevin Lu-MSFT has provided  an answer on your another case for the API issue. I also have checked with the script shared in that answer and it can work fine. Please try with it.
